# Why can't I login in amazon aws through my virtual os(Bodhi Linux) but I can login from windows(host os)?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, browser, login

I have windows OS and through a browser(Brave Browser) I can login to my amazon AWS account.
I have installed virtual box and using Bodhi Linux on it and trying to login to AWS account with the help of Brave browser but I can't login. The error its showing :

> **This site can't be reached**
>
> **signin.aws.amazon.com** too too long to
> respond.

I can login through my ***host OS(windows)***, ***mobile phone*** but not from the *browser in **Bodhi Linux***. *Internet connection* is there in Bodhi Linux and I can browse but can't login to AWS account. Tried to login from different browsers *Chromium* and *Brave* but can't login to AWS account through both of them.

Don't have any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do other pages work in Bodhi Linux?

Comment: Yes other pages works

Comment: Waiting for superusers

Comment: Spin up a test machine (Ubuntu) and see if that works. Make sure Networking in NAT or Bridged and NOT Host Only.

Comment: In Bodhi Linux I can browse and do all internet stuffs but just can't sign in to aws account but I can sign in to aws from the host os(windows os). Its weird and have no idea why this is happening?

Comment: There are some setup instructions for bodhi linux.  Be sure to follow them.  ...... https://www.bodhilinux.com/w/virtualbox-and-bodhi-as-guest/#:~:text=With%20VirtualBox%20(Host)%20installed%20you,as%20a%20guest%20operating%20system.

Comment: Thanks @John I have installed `Bodhi Linux` properly.

Comment: Try a different Linux Guest to see

Comment: Installed a new `Guest OS(arch)` in the `Oracle Virtual box` but there also I can't login to **amazon aws account**. I have checked and internet connection is there in Guest OS and I can browse internet. What do you thing @John why is this happening why from `Guest OS` we can't login to **amazon aws account** from browser?

Comment: I do not know. I assume you are using Default NAT networking and that should work. So I have run out of ideas except perhaps to try a trial version of VMware and see it that works better. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Yes I'm using NAT networking

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with Arch Linux and VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Arch Linux and VirtualBox. The problem was related to my DNS Filter system. I just had to add the domain *.aws.amazon.com to the AllowList. Now the question is why the Host was allowed but the Guest was not (both are using the same network and DNS Filter system). Please take into account that you have to change your Network type from Nat to Bridge